# presto sql to find ids having specific column values inserted in sequence

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table

```
user_id  user_type   date_updated

1         Beginner   10/10/2020
1         Moderate   10/11/2020
1         Advanced   10/12/2020
2         Beginner   10/10/2020
2         Moderate   10/11/2020
2         Expert     10/12/2020
2         Advanced   10/13/2020
```

I am looking for **sql to find user_ids** with **user_type** (Beginner->Moderate->Advanced) ordered by date_updated in sequentially increasing manner.

Result from above table should be user_id 1 as it has Beginner(10/10/2020) -> Moderate(10/11/2020) -> Advanced(10/12/2020)

user_id 2 is not qualified because all there required types are not followed by each other Beginner->Moderate->***Expert***->Advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation with conditional logic in the `having`:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having max(case when user_type = 'Beginner' then date_updated end) < max(case when user_type = 'Moderate' then date_updated end) and
       max(case when user_type = 'Moderate' then date_updated end) < max(case when user_type = 'Advanced' then date_updated end);
```

EDIT:

Based on the revised question, use `lag()`.  Assuming there are no duplicate user types for a given user:

```
select user_id
from (select t.*,
             lag(user_type) over (partition by user_id order by date_updated) as prev_user_type,
             lag(user_type, 2) over (partition by user_id order by date_updated) as prev2_user_type
      from t
     ) t
where prev2_user_type = 'Beginner' and
      prev_user_type = 'Moderate' and
      user_type = 'Advanced'
```

Comment: I also don't want any other user_type between all the required ones. updated the question with more precise detail.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select user_id
from mytable
group by user_id
having array_agg(user_type order by date_updated) = array['Beginner', 'Moderate', 'Advanced']
```